# AutoHotkey and Credentials

Tags: autohotkey, credentials

Use Case: I want the launching of an Autohotkey to be secure.

I intend to make it capable of posting passwords, but I want the launching and editing of this script to prompt for credentials. Are there any built-in options for me to consider. Alternatives for the copying and pasting of passwords will also suffice.

Answer (score 0):

You can compile the code into a password protected EXE file and run the ahk file as an AHK file.

https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/85482-password-on-exe-or-file/

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think compiled ahk scripts can be easily reviewed to find the underlying ahk cleartext code.  In this case, the password is hardcoded into the code and could be discerned.  Better to take the password from the protect dialog and hash it before appending the code with pw to the ahk file.  Then take the input box result and run the same hash to do the compare.  But, even that can be "cracked."  Why don't you store pw's in a secure vault and have ahk retrieve them when needed?

Comment: 'easily' is a relative term, but yes, they can indeed be decompiled and the keys extracted.

Answer (score 0):

In AutoHotKey, you can easily put up a dialog box to prompt for a password when the script starts.

The following is verbatim from the reference manual:

```
InputBox, password, Enter Password, (your input will be hidden), hide
```

You can put it at the top of the script.

Here is a script similar in structure to one I am using; it binds the  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> key to activate a particular window, simulate a click and some <kbd>Tab</kbd> keystrokes, and then enters the password and hits <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

```
#SingleInstance Force

InputBox, password, Enter Password, (your input will be hidden), hide

^!v::
if WinExist("WINDOW TITLE HERE") {
  WinActivate
  MouseClick, left, 400, 60
  SendInput {Tab}{Tab}{Tab}
  SendRaw %password%
  Send {Enter}
}
```

The `Inputbox` is executed when you launch the script; you must type the password. The password goes into the `password` variable, which is then used each time you invoke the hot-key sequence.

This almost satisfies the question's requirement:

> I want the launching and editing of this script to prompt for credentials.

If you want to create a two-field dialog box that prompts for multiple credential pieces, like user name and password, there are GUI functions for that; AutoHotKey supports a whole zoo of controls. Tab panels, combo boxes, multi-line edits, you name it.